# Regarding the Poincare Friedrichs inequality

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on a two part problem. Part 1 was to prove the Poincare-Friedrichs inequality for n=1:

$\int_{0}^{\alpha} |f(t)|^2 dt \le C\int_{0}^{\alpha} |f'(t)|^2 dt$

for some constant $C$. I managed to do this using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Part 2 is to show there does not exist a constant $C > 0$ such that

$\int_{0}^{\alpha} |f'(t)|^2 dt \le C\int_{0}^{\alpha} |f(t)|^2 dt$.

It's been a while since I've done proofs of this sort and I am not sure what is the best strategy for proving non-existence. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is f and \alpha?

Comment: Sorry, $\alpha$ is a positive scalar and $f$ is a continuously differentiable function on $[0,\alpha]$ such that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: look here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545656/prove-friedrichs-inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part take $f_m (\xi )= \xi ^m$ then we have $$\frac{n}{2}=\int_0^1 |f_n'(x)|^2 dx\leq C\int_0^1 |f_n(x)|^2 dx =\frac{C}{2n+1} \mbox{for all } n\in\mathbb{N}$$ which is impossible.

Comment: Thank you. So it looks like to prove nonexistence the best technique is to assume existence and reach a contradiction?