# Show that there is a constant so that the inequality stands

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $U$ open and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Show that there is a positive constant $c$ such that it holds that $$\int_U |u|^2dx \leq c \int_U |\nabla{u}|^2dx, \forall u \in H_0^1(U)$$

Could you give me some hints how we could do that??

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545656/prove-friedrichs-inequality

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to accept to Sobolev inequality this is straightforward. For a function $g : U \to \mathbb R$ define 
$$g^*(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} g(x)  & x \in U \\ 0 & x \notin U. \end{array} \right.$$ You can show using the definition of weak derivative that if $u \in H^1_0(U)$, then $u^* \in H^1(\mathbb R^n)$ and that $\nabla (u^*) = (\nabla u)^*$.  In this case the Sobolev inequality states
$$
\int_U |u|^2 \, dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n} |u^*| \, dx \le c \int_{\mathbb R^n} |\nabla (u^*)|^2 \ dx = c \int_{U} |\nabla u|^2 \, dx.$$